# how to remove/delete cache from react app in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a react app and due to some reason
i deleted the file containing my json data from my app but it's contents is  still showing , maybe its cause of cache in react so, anyone know how to delete react app cache ?

I tried to clear cache by using these commands, but is not working at all

note: My react app run on local

```
 npm rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
    npm rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
    npm  rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-*
    npm cache clean --force
    npm cache rm --force
    npm rm -rf node_modules
    remove node module
    npm install
    npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the application tab on the browser dev tools and refresh cache storage.

you could use this [guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-clear-complete-cache-data-in-reactjs/) for better understanding and how to do it with your code

Comment: I have also used this method but that was nothing data

Comment: does this same happen with an incognito browser window?

Comment: yes, I also tried with diffrent browser